# How to make hammerjs events fire only once?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, hammer.js

I'm using the latest build of hammerjs (1.0.6). The jquery build they have is a bit buggy with requirejs, so I'm just using the standard build.

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/mcfarljw/fDYx3/

How can I get this tap event to fire once and then remove itself? I thought it would have been as simple as calling off, but that appears not to be the case. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
var tapCount = 0;
Hammer($('#box')[0]).on('tap', function() {
    tapCount++
    $('#counter').text(tapCount);
    Hammer($('#box')[0]).off('tap');
});
```

Comment: Then you just want to let the user tap just one time, right?

Comment: Use `.one()` method instead of `.on()`.

Comment: Yes, I'd like it to fire once and then remove itself. @BlackSheep, this isn't jquery so there is no one method.

Comment: Hammer has a jQuery version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
var tapCount = 0;
var callback = function() {
tapCount++
$('#counter').text(tapCount);
Hammer($('#box')[0]).off('tap',callback);
};
Hammer($('#box')[0]).on('tap', callback );
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/EuSK4/

Comment: So it looks like the event can't be removed until it has officially completed firing? Or rather it needs to be able to reference the callback function.

Comment: It needs to reference the callback function, because if you call it this way: Hammer($('#box')[0]).on('tap'); it's the same as: Hammer($('#box')[0]).on('tap', undefined );

Answer (score 0):

To fire the event only once, you need to store the reference to the manager instance that binds the event & use the same instance to unbind it.

http://jsfiddle.net/a8f1p6pt/3/

```
var hInstance ;
var handler = function() {
    alert('Alert Once');
    hInstance.off('tap', handler);
};
hInstance = Hammer($('#box')[0]);
hInstance.on('tap', handler );
```